# What does "MyType.()" mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

This expression doesn't look like a lambda that accepts an `Int` and returns an `Int`

```
lateinit var myVar: Int.() -> Int
```

What does `Int.()` mean in Kotlin? How to assign something to `myVar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin supports the concept of [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions).

A type definition like `Foo.(Bar) -> Baz` describes a functional type, that takes an object of type `Foo` as its **receiver**, accepts an argument of type `Bar` and returns an object of type `Baz`.

This allows to synthetically add extensions to a type that you cannot control. For example, you may add an extension to `String` and invoke it, like it was defined on the class itself.

```kotlin
fun String.hasEvenLength(): Boolean = this.size % 2 == 0

val result = "foo".hasEvenLength()
```

The `this` keyword inside an extension function corresponds to the receiver object (the one that is passed before the dot).

Answer (score 3):

`Int` is called a receiver here. `myVar` is basically a variable holding an extension function. This means that in scope of this function keyword `this` will refer to the `Int` object, on which it has been called.

So you would assign `myVar` as e.g. `myVar = { this }` and call like `42.myVar()`.

Comment: Most of this answer seems good, but are you sure `myVar` is a literal? Seems like just a variable.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I called it 'literal'. Edited the answer for more clarity.